# Display images with Greek in filenames

Tags: filenames

I'm building an e-shop in greek and i've come across an important issue regarding the image filenames that users upload to the linux server. If the filename contains greek chars then the file is uploaded normally but the images won't display in the browser. It's important to us that greek filenames are supported as we are counting on searches in greek for both web and image results on Google.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin. Particularly since you've given us nothing to go on.

Comment: When you do POST for the image you mean the image is not returned back to browser?

Comment: @casperOne Silly question, but why were you editing this two year old question?

Comment: @MrLister http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because of server charset filename issue? While your filename is in greek
server translate it at something like `Αήι;;`΄'.jpg`and you have to img src`Αήι;;`΄'.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't they displaying?  Do you have an example?

I guess your options depend on how the images are being stored and served back to the users.  One thing you could do, in order to preserve the Greek text on the page for search results, may be to serve up the files with a non-Greek name and write the Greek part to the image's `alt` tag.

This, however, is assuming that you're storing the image files in conjunction with a database of some kind which would contain the necessary meta-data.  Basically, upon upload, the image's meta-data (`alt` text, maybe mime type, anything else important about it) would be written to a record in a database table and then the image file itself can be saved on the file system.  Its actual file name could just be the primary key from the table, which can just be an auto-increment field.

Comment: just came across this old question and your question made me wonder, why not store the image on the db as a blob as well? Is it just to avoid duplicating all the metadata? Would it not be safer/easier to control if it were on the db? Though harder to visually inspect at a glance, obviously...

Comment: @Alex: It's an age-old question that has no definite answer.  I tend to be of the mindset that if you're storing/serving files, use the tools that are designed for that purpose... the file system and the web server.  And let the relational database track relational data.  Certainly one can store files in the database, and lots of applications do this.  It's not really my preference, but sometimes it makes sense depending on other factors and software requirements.

Comment: The old "it depends" rears its head once more :) But it's true, of course - when you have so many tools at your disposal, there's hardly ever a concrete right and wrong. Good point on using the file system and db for what they're designed for, though.

Comment: @Alex: I suppose I could further quantify the "it depends" response with an example.  If the files are something well known and tightly constrained, such as system-generated user avatars on a forum or even user-uploaded avatars with type/size/space constraints, then that's probably fine.  If the files being stored are just a user document repository, the file system may be better suited for the task.  (This exact subject came up at my current client engagement recently and I asked, "What if a user scans in a document at 9600 DPI by accident?"  The DBA quickly sided with my file system idea.)

Comment: Hehe that's a great example, I'll try to remember it :)